# SWD Connection to MCU and Appropriate Configuration for Reset Pin

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, schematics, optoelectronics, swd

I aim to establish a connection between SWD header and an STM32 MCU on PCB, having identified the relevant pins on MCU (SWO, SWCLK, and SWDIO). I have two inquiries:

1. Is it appropriate to connect directly to the MCU pins, or should I
   incorporate bypass capacitors, basic filter circuits or anything
   else?
2. Is it advisable to connect directly to the NRST pin, incorporating
   ESD protection as illustrated in the attached schematics?

Kindly provide guidance and recommendations.
[image]

Comment: 1. Usualy direct, but if you have connector with pins exposed to touches, you can add ESD protection. 2. Your connection seems ok to me. Some people add external pulup also. It better define time constant for low pass filter consisting pullup and 100nF C? Now it depends only on internall pullup (25k - 55k). More details about recommendation when using STM32s on own board are in app notes named "Getting started with STM32xx Series hardware development". You do not mention family used, so you need it to find it yourself on page of MCU you use on Documentation tab in Application Note section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only goal is programming under controlled environment, there is no need to have any special arrangements.

Unless it is expected that using the programming header will be exposed to users, like a hobbyist board where connections to SWD header is expected under normal use.

Capacitors would slow down signals so they would not work.

But the reset needs capacitor anyway. 100nF can swamp ESD before voltage rises to unsafe levels.

I'd be more worried about the button shorting the cap directly, instead of ESD.

The capacitor on BOOT0 makes no sense either, the voltage is always pulled low.